# Issues in integrating with Multitenant app added in Azure Active directory while the site is under load balancer

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I have added a multitenant app in Azure active directory. And I have a MVC webapp which I have integrated with this multitenant app, where user can log in by providing their Office 365 account credentials. I have pre-configured the reply urls in the multitenant app in azure so that after authenticating the users, it redirects to my MVC  webapp correctly. The reply url I have configured is http://servername/v1 and the URL from where user redirects to Azure login page(http://login.windows.net) from my MVC webapp is http://servername/v1/azure/verifyaccount.

Now when I test my app either from localhost or a QA server all works fine, which means user comes to http://servername/v1/azure/verifyaccount and redirects to http://login.windows.net. After user provides credentials and Azure verifies it, it posts back to http://servername/v1/azure/verifyaccount correctly.

But when I test on a integration server which is under load balancer, after verifying the user credentials, Azure posts to http://servername/v1/ instead of http://servername/v1/azure/verifyaccount. Since http://servername/v1/ is not configured as post url, I receive an HTTP 404 error in the browser.

Has anybody encountered this issue before. Let me know how I can fix this issue. Also let me know if any more details are needed.

Comment: Hi, what protocol are you using? WS-Federation or OpenId Connect? Thanks

Comment: we are using OpenIdConnect.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple reply url in azure AD application, so add http://servername/v1/ to your reply url and it should work